# Shiny Server get number of records in a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to learn shiny and to read in an excel sheet and show both the contents of the excel sheet and the number of records in the UI

I'm a bit lost. when i read in the data set, how do i reference the dataframe that i have read in

```
# Server Code
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Read the Data in
 library(xlsx)

  # Output the actual Table
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    test_df <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath,1)
    test_df
    )})

  # Output the number of records to check
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Number of records is:", nrow(test_df))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice would be to have your `library` calls and any `read_*` functions in your global.R file (which should be in the same directory as server.R and ui.R. global.R will be parsed at the beginning of your web application and the file will be available in both the ui and the server (though you only need it in the server here).

So something like:

```
#in globar.R
library(xlsx)
test_df <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath,1)

#and server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Output the actual Table
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    test_df
    )})

  # Output the number of records to check
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Number of records is:", nrow(test_df))
  })

})
```

should work fine.

Comment: Hi, @LyzandeR, This is great. just to clarify for myself, i should create another R script file called globar.R and the shiny app will automatically know its there like app.R and server.R

Comment: Exactly. shiny is programmed to look for the global.R in the same way it looks for ui.R and server.R.